# Unable to predict values for a given input date in ARIMA using predict() function

Tags: python, date, datetime, predict, arima

I am using the following code for arima to predict values of output for the given date value from `2018-10-17` to `2018-10-22`. But I get the error as

> ERROR:
>   "int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Timestamp'".

```
model = ARIMA(df, order=(5,1,0))
model = model.fit(disp=0)
pred = model.get_prediction(start=pd.to_datetime('2018-10-17'),
                            end=pd.to_datetime('2018-10-22'),
                            dynamic=True)
```

Doesn't `predict()` accept `datetime` objects? It says it does in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using [`statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAXResults.get_prediction`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAXResults.get_prediction.html), notice that `start` and `end` expect an `int`, `str`, or datetime. Per the docs, the str can be a date string, so you could use

```
pred = model.get_prediction(start='2018-10-17', 
                            end='2018-10-22',
                            dynamic=True)
```

---

[Pandas Timestamps](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html) are not the same as [Python datetime.datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) objects.

If you wish to use a datetime, use the [`Timestamp.to_pydatetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.to_pydatetime.html) method to convert Pandas Timestamps to Python datetime.datetime objects:

```
In [181]: pd.to_datetime('2018-10-17')
Out[181]: Timestamp('2018-10-17 00:00:00')

In [180]: pd.to_datetime('2018-10-17').to_pydatetime()
Out[180]: datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 17, 0, 0)
```

or simply create the datetime.datetime object directly:

```
In [184]: import datetime as DT

In [185]: DT.datetime(2018,10,17)
Out[185]: datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 17, 0, 0)

pred = model.get_prediction(start=DT.datetime(2018, 10, 17), 
                            end=DT.datetime(2018, 10, 22),
                            dynamic=True)
```